# Putting clustered index on a join used column vs heavily scanned column?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have this simple table :

Table `Users`

```
userId    |  name    
--------------------- 
 1             'a1'   
 2             'a2'    
 3             'a3'    
 4             'a4'    
 5             'a5'
```

Table `Cities`

```
cityId    |  name    
--------------------- 
 1             'c1'   
 2             'c2'    
 3             'c3'    
 4             'c4'    
 5             'c5'
```

Each user is can be in **more**  than one city. :

So the mapping table is :

```
userId    |  CityId    
------------------------------------
 1             4    
 1             4    
 1             4    
 2             5    
 5             6
```

Table `users` is heavily scanned by name .

Question :

For the mapping table I have no issues. both columns together are primary/clustered index.

But i'm struggling with myself about the first 2 tables :

- I think that Users  should have `userId` column as primary key. why ? because it is used throug the join to the mapping table.
- but I also need clustered index on the name column cause this table is heavily scanned by name.

*(leave aside the unique problem. lets say all columns are unique)*

What is the best practice decision for this case ?

Comment: What's wrong with an index on the name ..? A covering index (name, id) may avoid a trip back to the primary data in some cases ..

Comment: i cant have 2 clustered indexes. then , i wont have an index on the id column which is used (also )for join

Comment: I don't see how it's a problem. PK/clustered (id); then Index(name) or Index (name, id) if covering helps. Testing should show if using the latter makes a difference in this case.

Comment: @user2246674 clustered index are much faster than non-clustered. and i do need speed scanning by name.

Comment: Indexes are "clustered" (using the term loosely here) along their axis. Thus a covering index can be "clustered" over the cover. A non-covering index may need to seek back into the primary data - seeing wether or not this matters really requires some testing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, clustered index is not much faster than non-clustered index, maybe slightly faster. Any index is much faster than no index at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best decision depends on how exactly you use the data returned by a query.

A clustered index means that the data in the page files are ordered based on this index.

A regular index will have it's own page files to order the index and a pointer to the physical row.

Thus a clustered index will serve better for theses queries that return a range of value instead of unique rows.

So, unless you do a lot of queries with `like` operations on the `Name` column, you would be better to keep your clustered index on the `ID` column, for this index will be constantly scanned and used to return recordsets to support your join operations.

Comment: So a `Join` column should have a higher priority for candidate to be clustered Key. (although I do a lot of `where name=...` {as opposed  to  `%like%`})...?

Comment: Yes, because even if you do a lot of `where name=` each request will have to seek and access each row individually, a clustered index wouldn't really boost boost the performance here. The join in the other hand, will access a range of data sequentially thus you will get a bigger boost from the clustered index (since it won't have to move back and forth in the data pages).